# AngularJS how to Parse an entire custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this piece of code for a custom directive I made in AngularJS. It lists some info for a panel and when the user clicks on a panel it shows more info. The information all displays as unmarked and untrusted HTML code. I'm not sure what to use to get to use $sce.trustAsHtml() for all the HTML in the entire directive.

```
app.directive('taskListing', function($sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/elements/tasklisting.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, $sce){
            //Obj = $sce.trustAsHtml(Obj);
            element.on("click", function(){
                angular.element("tbody.task-tbody tr").toggleClass("hidden"); 
                });
            },
        };
    });
```

Comment: Don't know what `Obj` is, but you should 1st remove `$sce` from `link` function & then try..

Comment: I can't parse the HTML if I remove it.